# For $\theta_t=\theta_{xx}.$ Find by substitution solutions of the form $\theta(x,t) = f(t)\exp[-(x+a)^2/4(t+b)] $ for arbitrary $a$ and $b$.

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

Consider the diffusion equation
$$\theta_t=\theta_{xx}.$$
Find by substitution solutions of the form
$$\theta(x,t) = f(t)\exp[-(x+a)^2/4(t+b)]   $$
for arbitrary $a$ and $b$.
Now I used the substitution $v=x/\sqrt{t}$. Now $\theta(x,t)=\psi(v)$. By the chain rule 
$$\theta_t = \psi' v_t=\psi' \frac{-v}{2t},$$
$$\theta_{xx} = (\psi'v_x)_x=\psi''v_x^2 + \psi'v_{xx}=\frac{\psi''}{t}.$$
We use this information in the original DE and cancel the $t$ to obtain
$$ \frac{-v}{2}\psi'=\psi''.$$
We rearrange to get
$$\frac{-v}{2} =\frac{\psi''}{\psi'}=\frac{d}{dv} \ln (\psi').$$
Integrating gives
$$-\frac{v^2}{4} = \ln \psi' + C$$
so that $\psi '=C\exp(-v^2/4)$. Where do I continue from here? Thanks for any help :)

As a side note, I choose this substitution instead of $v = (x+a)/(\sqrt{t+b}$ because I can easily show that if $\theta(x,y)$ is a solution then so is $\theta(x+a,t+b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: I suggest you go the other way round. You already have a candidate. Just substitute the given function 
$$     f(t)  \exp[−(x+a)^2/4(t+b)]$$
onto your PDE to obtain a ODE on $f$. It will be (after removing exponentials) something like:
$$     f' + g(x,t)f = fh(x,t) $$
With any luck you should be able to solve this equation on $f$. Note that, in the end, if a solution by substitution is to be found, it should happen that $h(x,t)-g(x,t)=j(t)$ and thus the process should be straightforward.

Comment: Ah of course, thats probably what the original question asked for :) Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I still wonder though, it feels like I am pretty close to an answer in my original workings but I feel like I made a mistake somewhere...

Comment: What you were doing is how one comes up with the exponential part. I wouldn't pursue that line much further.